# How do I change the colour of the link on my Blog page?

Tags: css, text, colors, hyperlink, customising

On the blog page of my website the text of links to my blog posts are the colour blue, & I would like to change them to a different colour.

I have tried searching for an answer on google but have found nothing!

My website is http://bentleyandhudson.com/blog

If you click through to my website you can see poochplay ~ dog activity tracker is in blue this is the text I would like to change.

Comment: just add in a {
    color: black;
}

Comment: Where do I add this to?

Comment: show my answer and mt edit

Comment: @annabelle do you want to change only color of this anchor tag or color of all anchor tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your website is a WordPress website, so you can change the link in your blog page this way:

In your website there is a file:
http://bentleyandhudson.com/wp-content/themes/bento/style.css

Edit it by adding the following code to the end of it:

```
.blog .post .entry-header .entry-title a{
    color:black;
}
.blog .post .entry-header .entry-title a:hover{
    color:grey;
}
```

Be sure to reload the browser cache to load the changes added to the `style.css` file. (Press CTRL+F5)

To add the color to every link in your website, add this code to the style.css file:

```
a{
    color:black;
}
a:hover{
    color:grey;
}
```

To change the link color of posts on the sidebar `"PE Recent Posts"` add this code:

```
.pe-recent-posts-title-tag a{
    color:black;
}
.pe-recent-posts-title-tag a:hover{
    color:grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your css:

```
 a { 
color: black; }
```

If you want to change the color **on hover**:

```
 a:hover {
 color: red; }
```

**EDIT**
spesific class:

```
<a class="class1"></a>
```

In css:

```
.class1{
 color: black;}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: it will change all anchor tags color!!! may  be OP question to change only particular anchor tag color

Comment: so add spesific class to this a

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific:

```
h2.entry-title a {
     color:green;
}
h2.entry-title a:hover {
     color:red;
}
```